# Shared VPC Interconnect

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have configured an Interconnect connection to my on-premise network and it is working perfectly. Now I want to shared this connection to other VPCs and I enabled the shared VPC option, my project is as host and the second project is as service.

The problem I have is when I tried to configured the shared-interconnect in the service project I got the message:

> The resource 'projects/host-project-name/global/interconnects/xxxxxxx' was not found.

Now, on my host project I don't see the interconnect name I only see the attached vlans which are both up.

I also ran the command on the shell, but I did not get any result:

```
 ricardo_ramos@cloudshell:~ (hosting-project-name)$ gcloud compute interconnects list
```

Listed 0 items.

Any thoughts about this? someone had the same issue before?

Thanks in advance,

Ricardo.

Comment: Are the VPC unique (no overlapping CIDR blocks)?

Comment: Remember that you cannot create VLAN attachments and Cloud Routers in the Service Project, only in the Host Project.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are actually referring as shared-interconnect, are you referring to [Partner Interconnect](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/choose-type#partner)? If you are using partner interconnect then physical interconnects for partner interconnects exists in the partner's own projects. The customer's project (customer of the partner interconnect) should only have an interconnect attachment (VLAN attachment).